# Saving Metadata to R csv file

Tags: metadata

I have a csv file whose first 15 lines are all metadata information. The actual data starts on line 16. I use read.csv with "skip = 15" option to load the data and process the data. When I save the new processed data, I like to save it as a csv file with the 15 lines of metadata added to it. I don't have any clue on how to do that in R.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

we start from a csv file with some comments/metadata in the head:

```
cat /tmp/original.csv
# first line
# second line of metadata
key,name,value
1,"Alice",10
2,"Bob",5
```

then, in R:

```
    # read the file
    df <- read.csv('/tmp/original.csv',skip = 2, stringsAsFactors = F)

    # read the metadata
    metadata <- readLines('/tmp/original.csv', 2)

    # change some value
    df$value = df$value * 2

    # save the metadata
    writeLines('/tmp/modified.csv',text = metadata)

    # append the data.frame
    write.table(d, file = '/tmp/modified.csv', append = T, row.names = F, sep = ',')
```

in bash:

```
cat /tmp/modified.csv
# first line
# second line of metadata
"key","name","value"
1,"Alice",20
2,"Bob",10
```

as you can see, we can't use write.csv. for more info:

```
?write.csv
```

> These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to
>   ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file.
>   Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod are ignored,
>   with a warning.